# Elements not showing in Background Page Inspector and getting addEventListener is null error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension, so I'm doing tutorials to learn and reading a bunch, but I'm struggling.  I'm doing [this tutorial](https://dev.to/aurelkurtula/basics-of-chrome-extensions-development-part-two-82p).  But long-term, from the extension I need users to be able to login to their account, then as they're browsing, send the url that they're at to their account.

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add a Snippet</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Add a Snippet</h1>
   <form id="form">
     <textarea id="code"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="checkPage">Add Snippet</button>
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**
What I REALLY don't understand is that according to the console.log lines that I have in there and the error, it's loading the DOMContent, and it doesn't have any problem with finding the form by the id (let f = document.getElementById('form');).  But it bombs when I try to attach an event listener?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
console.log('the domcontentloaded');
  let f = document.getElementById('form');
    f.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    console.log('the form was submitted');
        e.preventDefault();
    })
}, false);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My Awesome Plugin",
  "description": "This extension will be awesome",
  "version": "1.0",
 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "This is Awesome"
 },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "background.js","popup.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
 "content_scripts": [
     {
         "matches": [
             "<all_urls>"
         ],
         "js": ["login.js"]
     }
 ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**login.js**

```
console.log('login.js is ready to party');
```

When I load, I get this in the background inspector (or whatever it's called).  So it's not finding the form.
[image]

So I looked at the elements, and I'm confused because it's not showing the form or the textarea.  But when I click on the chrome extension icon, it's there.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The documentation is probably absolutely terrible as it fails to convey some basic concepts properly to a lot of newcomers. The thing is, the background page is a separate hidden page, not related to your popup page so there's no need to load popup.js in the background. To debug the popup, right-click the popup, then click inspect.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your reply!  This was very helpful!

Comment: @wOxxOm  Submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

1/Remove popup.js from "background/scripts" section of your manifest.
2/Add popup.js as a script reference in your popup.html file.

This way, popup.js will operate in the context of the popup.html DOM.